# RockMongo Collections View - Error Description make encrpytion

Tags: encryption, rockmongo

I have installed and implemented the rockmongo tool and auth things are going cool. but while viewing the collections description the popup shows to view the data which are simple text, i need to show it as encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

finally myself cracked it...changed some javascript code in Js Folder and i got the popup with decrypt.....

File name called collection.js where you can customize the popup

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).